# iOS: Fetch logs from Instruments in txt format

Tags: ios, format, instruments, logging

Is there any way i can fetch the test cases logs that are generated from Instrument in text format. I want it to be passed on to a text file so that i can read them and create a Test Report.

Answer (score 0):

Some (but not all) tools in Instruments support exporting to CSV.

To do so, select the instrument you want and click

`Instrument -> Export Data for:`